# Ошибка синтаксиса в INSERT базы данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Добрый день.
Как сделать вставку в таблицу массива? Пробовал через format:

```
insert ="""INSERT INTO gprs(q,w,e,r,t,y) VALUES('{},{},{},{},{},{}.format(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]))"""
cursor.execute(insert)
```

Выводит ошибку с синтаксисом

> MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'ok', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false'

Примечательно что один из элементов массива содержит в себе массив со значениями ok, false

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать следующим образом:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO gprs(q,w,e,r,t,y) VALUES ({},{},{},{},{},{})'.format(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5])
cursor.execute(sql)
```